# Computing Multivariable Definite Integral On TI-Nspire

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, calculator

Whenever I try running the following integral on the Ti-Nspire, I get an "undef" error:

integral (0,inf) of x^2 * (1/y)^(-x/y) dx

Comment: I don't know about the syntax, but note that the output is a function of $y$. Perhaps you can rewrite the integral in some other form, because it seems to be of the form
$$
\int x^2 e^{k\cdot x}\,dx
$$
Also, I think the value of the integral at infinity diverges, so most certainly the answer is not a real number anyway.

Comment: The output is a function of y, and can easily be computed using just your typical definite integral calculator online, Im just confused why TI-nspire cant give me the same output